# How can I avoid a node is crawled and indexed by search engines in the tightest way possible?

Tags: nodes, 10

I have a node whose path alias is /example, where I test JavaScript and often share it with fellow JavaScript programmers to consult about how best to do something.

I often need to post the URL for that node in forums and Q&A sites and I fear that it would cause SEO damage to my website because this webpage looks awful, doesn't have almost any logic, and may cause search engine crawlers to falsely signal that my website is "non qualitative."

To ensure that search engines never crawl and hence never index this webpage, I have added the following line to the *robots.txt* file.

```
Disallow: /example
```

I am not sure if that's enough, though. Not all search engines will necessarily respect robots.txt. I could add a `noindex` tag to that node somehow.

How can I avoid a node is crawled and indexed by search engines in the tightest way possible?
Does Drupal have its own mechanism for that, to add a `noindex` tag or any other thing I might have missed?

Comment: You can add noindex headers to specific content with https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag but noindex headers are no better than robots.txt in a case like this. You would actually have to block all known crawlers with a special module to really eliminate crawlers.

Comment: Or just don't do this in prod, period. Otherwise, look into content access solutions to 100% eliminate anonymous access outside of crawlers.

Comment: @Kevin if its not on prod, on the web, I won't be able so share the webpage for live testing with a browser console. I don't know what is the meaning of "content access solutions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Drupal has a mechanism to block all crawlers in the “tightest way possible”: authentication.

Comment: Can I use Drupal core to protect a specific node with a password? I didn't find a way (or a module) to do it in Drupal 10.

Comment: For a specific node, https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_pages or custom code.